# PostInsertEventListener no funciona cuando inserto un nuevo elemento usando clase Main

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Tengo un problema con los `EventListeners` de Hibernate. Primero les diré en que consiste mi aplicación, les dejare el código de las clases y luego les expondré el problema.

Estoy desarrollando en Spring en su versión 4, y empleo Hibernate en su versión 5. Primeramente hice una entidad llamada Person para guardar datos de personas en una base de datos.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1072254302801682898L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String country;
    //Getters y setters
```

Siguiendo los ejemplos de los tutoriales, cree las interfaces DAO y los servicios que me permitirían salvar los datos.

```
public interface PersonService {

    public void addPerson(Person p);
    public void updatePerson(Person p);
    public void removePerson(int id);

}

@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    @Autowired
    public void setPersonDAO(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        this.personDAO.addPerson(p);
    }
    //EL update y el delete ya estan implementados
```

Clases DAO

```
public interface PersonDAO {

    public void addPerson(Person p);
    public void updatePerson(Person p);
    public void removePerson(int id);
}

@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(p);
        logger.info("Person saved successfully, Person Details=" + p);
    }
```

Y con el PostInserteventListener, cada vez que inserto una persona guardo en un registro datos de la operación ejecutada:

```
public class InsertarEvento implements PostInsertEventListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Registro reg;
    Salvador sav;
    private Date date;
    private String operation;

    @Override
    public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof Person) {
            Object p = event.getEntity();           
            System.out.println("+++Person inserted+++" + p);
            operation = "Insertada una persona";
            date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            reg = new Registro(operation, date);
            sav = new Salvador();
            sav.saveData(reg);
            }       
    }
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, cada vez que inserto una persona (mediante una vista que contiene un formulario) el `listener` se activa. Sin embargo ahora tengo muchas mas entidades que insertar y para no hacer mas vistas. ni clases `DAO` otra vez, hice una clase `Main` donde creo los objetos y los persisto. Les dejo un ejemplo de como salvo ahora una persona:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("New person");
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName("pepe");
        p.setCountry("mexico");
        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        ses.beginTransaction();
        ses.save(p);
        ses.getTransaction().commit();
        ses.close();
        System.out.println(p.getId());
    }
}
```

Con esto soy capaz de insertar personas en la base de datos, pero el `PostInsertEventListener` que implementé no se activa y no puedo registrar que operación se ejecuto sobre que entidad.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Por qué no se está ejecutando el `PostInsert` en el caso de usar una clase Main?

Comment: El problema es que en tu método `main` no estás registrando el event listener en el session factory. Es muy probable que en tu configuración por Spring sí lo hayas hecho a nivel de XML.

Comment: Como puedo registrar entonces el listener en este caso?